# Why bucket ARN ending with /* needs to be mentioned for resource in bucket Policy to allow user to upload the file

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-policies

I created S3 bucket and I have added one user in IAM. Suppose my bucuket name sample123. When in bucket ploicy I mentioned resource like below statement user is not able to upload document.

Resource":   "arn:aws:s3:::sample123"

But when resource is mentioned in policy as below , the user is able to upload document.

Resource":  [ "arn:aws:s3:::sample123","arn:aws:s3:::sample123/*"]

what adding /* to ARN will do in policy. Note : I gave full bucket permissions to the user.

Answer (score -1):

`sample123/*` means the all objects in sample123 bucket.

[doc of S3 ARN examples](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/s3-arn-format.html) says:

> The ARN format for Amazon S3 resources reduces to the following:
>
> arn:aws:s3:::bucket_name/key_name
>
> ...
>
> The following ARN uses the wildcard * in the relative-ID part of the
> ARN to identify all objects in the examplebucket bucket.
>
> arn:aws:s3:::examplebucket/*

Also refer [Example of S3 Actions with policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/using-with-s3-actions.html)